# Ubuntu 22.04 on Hostinger VPS1 and a spike in using disk space

Tags: vps, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on Hostinger VPS1 and a spike in using disk space for 2GB happened with out installing any package or doing abnormal thing! I would like to find the reason. Any help please?

I would like to find the reason. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons that could make this happen. I suggest checking the processes that are running on your VPS.

You can do this by running the `htop` command when logged into your VPS as a sudo user.

This will give you a list of all the processes running on your VPS (normally ordered by the amount of CPU usage). With this, you can navigate to the unusual process that is consuming disk space and kill it.

Be careful not to kill any important process.